# Ruby on Rails tutorial NoMethodError in Articles#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm following the official ROR tutorial at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
and I am stuck at section 5.8 where it teaches me how to list out all the articles

The following are my controller and index.html.erb

controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end


  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @article = Article.all
  end


  private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end


end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing articles</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

I am getting the `NoMethodError in Articles#index` with the error message

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"
```

What's wrong? I literally copied and pasted the code from the website to see what I'm doing wrong, but still cannot fix it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `@articles` and not `@article`

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all ## @articles and NOT @article
end
```

**`@articles` (plural) is semantically correct as you would be displaying a collection of articles in your view and not a single article.**

You are getting error

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

because in the `index` action, you have instantiated the instance variable `@article`(**NOTICE singular**) and are using `@articles`(**NOTICE plural**) in your `index` view i.e., `index.html.erb`. So, in the view `@articles`(plural) would be `nil` as it was never set. Hence, the error.

Comment: oh wow I can't believe I missed that after googling answers for the past hour.. thanks!

Comment: thanks very much for the clear explanation, it helped to lead me to fix the problem I had.

Answer (score 2):

Write as

```
<% @article.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

You have defined `@article` and not `@articles`. But good name is `@articles`, as it means collection of all article, thus use it in both places. *If you didn't define and attempt to use the any **instance variable**, it will return `nil`.* Now `Nilclass#each` not exist, thus you got a valid error.

Answer (score 2):

The **index action**

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all      
end
OR
def index
  @article = Article.all      
end
```

Both **@article** or **@articles** will work in views. But it depends upon you which one index action is taken.

If **@article** is taken then in view it should be

```
<% @article.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

If **@articles** is taken then in view it should be

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

**Note:-** It is good practice to take pluralize of instancle variable when it is a collection method

Hope this makes you clear on @articles and @article

Comment: Some explanation of your code might be in order.  A block of code by itself doesn't usually constitute a complete answer.

Comment: yes A block of code by itself doesn't usually constitute a complete answer but my answer was right. So if it not voted up then it should not be voted down.